# Alfresco - Error create user

Tags: alfresco

I'm trying to create a new user and the error message appears:

> Non-unique path: found : /app:company_home/app:user_homes 0

Any suggestions on how to resolve this error?

Answer (score 2):

This may happen if someone has definitely deleted the User Homes folder and this is throwing a wrench into the system. You need to disable home folder creation in alfresco-global.properties (property home.folder.creation.disabled = true), restart and re-create the expected folder (you need to use JavaScript API to get the child name right - a simple create folder / space won't suffice) before you can start your system normally again.
Refer this [community link](https://community.alfresco.com/thread/211708-non-unique-path-found-appcompanyhomeappuserhomes)